# C# mocking generic repository using Moq

Tags: c#, unit-testing, generics, moq

I have implemented generic repository in my project. Now I am writing test cases for my consumer. I am trying to mock database function through Moq but I am **getting values from database rather than the one I faked through Moq**. Below I am sharing my implementation. Hoping someone will help me in pointing out the mistake I made.

My interface:

```
public interface IEventsRepository<T> : IRepository<T>  {

T GetEventsByEventId(int eventId);  }
```

My class:

```
public class EventsTableRepository : EFDBRepository<EventsModel>, IEventsRepository<EventsModel>  {
public EventsModel GetEventsByEventId(int eventId)
{
  return _dbSet.Where(x => x.EventID == eventId).FirstOrDefault();
}
```

}

My Consumer:

```
public static Response<string> EventsAccept(EventsAlertsRequest logMsgId)
{
  IEventsRepository<EventsModel> eventsRepo = (IEventsRepository<EventsModel>)RepositoryLocator.GetRepositoryObject(STMEnums.RepositoryName.EventsTableRepository.ToString());
  EventsModel eventmodel = new EventsModel();
  eventmodel = eventsRepo.GetEventsByEventId(eachlogMsgId);
  return EventStatusChangeResponse;
}
```

Test Method:

```
public void EventsAcceptSuccessTest()
    {
        EventsModel eventmodel = new EventsModel();
        eventmodel.Message = "TEST";

        Mock<IEventsRepository<EventsModel>> obj = new Mock<IEventsRepository<EventsModel>>();
        obj.Setup(m => m.GetEventsByEventId(Moq.It.IsAny<int>())).Returns(eventmodel);

        EventStatusChangeResponse = Diagnostics_.EventsAccept(logMsgId);            
        Assert.AreEqual(eventmodel.Status, EventStatus.ACCEPTED);
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No where in the provided example is the mock being injected into the subject under test. Also it looks like the subject method under test is using static Service Locator anti-pattern to get the desired model. *Making an assumption here as the rest of the class is not shown in relation to that variable.*

The locator would need to have been an injected abstraction to allow an opportunity to mock its expected behavior

```
public class Consumer {
    private IRepositoryLocator RepositoryLocator;

    public Consumer(IRepositoryLocator RepositoryLocator) {
        this.RepositoryLocator = RepositoryLocator;
    }

    public Response<string> EventsAccept(EventsAlertsRequest logMsgId) {
      IEventsRepository<EventsModel> eventsRepo = (IEventsRepository<EventsModel>)RepositoryLocator.GetRepositoryObject(STMEnums.RepositoryName.EventsTableRepository.ToString());
      EventsModel eventmodel = new EventsModel();
      eventmodel = eventsRepo.GetEventsByEventId(eachlogMsgId);
      return EventStatusChangeResponse;
    }
}
```

This would then mean that the locator would also have to be mocked properly for the test to be exercised to completion.

```
public void EventsAcceptSuccessTest() {
    //Arrange
    var eventmodel = new EventsModel() {
        Message = "TEST"
    };

    var repositoryMock = new Mock<IEventsRepository<EventsModel>>();
    repositoryMock
        .Setup(_ => _.GetEventsByEventId(It.IsAny<int>()))
        .Callback((int id) => {
            eventmodel.EventID = id;
            eventmodel.Status = EventStatus.ACCEPTED;
        })
        .Returns(eventmodel);

    var locatorMock = new Mock<IRepositoryLocator>();
    locatorMock.Setup(_ => _.GetRepositoryObject(It.IsAny<string>())).Returns(repositoryMock.Object);

    var subject = new Consumer(locatorMock.Object);

    //Act
    var response = subject.EventsAccept(logMsgId);

    //Assert
    Assert.AreEqual(eventmodel.Status, EventStatus.ACCEPTED);
}
```

Comment: that works @nkosi Can you also help me in understanding '.Callback' thing. what it does and why I have to use it?

Comment: @user3891367 i forgot to include the Reference [Moq Quickstart](https://github.com/Moq/moq4/wiki/Quickstart) in the answer. You should review it to get a better understanding of that mocking framework.

Comment: @user3891367 based on your desired assertion it meant that the model needed to be updated after calling the method under test. the callback allows for that to happen after the mocked method was called.